# Can I put 14/2 Romex through a wiremold instead of inside the ceiling for a light fixture?

Tags: light-fixture, conduit

I have a closet with a light on the wall:

[image]

I would like to remove the light on the wall and instead create a new fixture on the ceiling, but using the same outlet. The ceiling is masonite tile, above that is a sheet of insulation foam, then drywall, then God knows what as insulation. To be honest, I don't feel like ripping up the ceiling in order to run 14/2 Romex through it.

I was thinking of running wire from the existing wall fixture, through the wall of course (RED BELOW), up to ceiling level, then having it somehow exit the wall and enter a tube wiremold (BLUE WOULD BE THE WIREMOLD), or conduit, unsure of the proper naming. And then finally into a fixture I found on Amazon (THE BLUE CIRCLE would be where I would put it):

[image]

[image]

I have a few questions about this:

First, is it a good idea? I know the wiremold doesn't look great but the alternative (trying to fish wire through the ceiling) isn't very appealing to me, as every time I open up a part of this main floor ceiling I find surprises.

Since the wire going to the existing light fixture isn't long enough to reach the center of the ceiling I assume I will need to splice some more 14/2 to the end of it, which requires a junction box, right? Is there a junction box model that I can use legally that can fit snuggly into the wall?

Also, when the wire exits the wall and enters the wiremold/conduit, how does that usually look? Is the wiremold perpendicularly flush with the wall? If so, I'm gonna have to cut some of the trim up there which is fine.

I'm not familiar with this type of wiring (yet) so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You can do that, but a better, easier solution that allows you to create even light all through your closet is to replace the fixture on the wall with an outlet where you plug in a low voltage LED strip and run that along the ceiling, along the back of the door frame, and down the sides of it to shine light at all levels onto the contents of the closet. You don't need conduit, you can use Staples or whatever you want to make it look nice, it's just 24 volts.  And with most decent ones there's an app to control the color too.

Comment: I may have missed it in your description, but that wall is going to have a top-plate above it that you'll need to get through.  Also, do you know which way the joists in the ceiling above run?  If they aren't running parallel to the line you're wanting to run, you'll have a lot of obstacles in your way.  If the "tube/wiremold" you mentioned would be external and run along the top of the ceiling, then why not use the same thing for the vertical run from the old light fixture?

Answer (score 4):

It's easy and viable to do what you describe and its a reasonable approach for a closet although I think there are better ways.   You might say that for a closet, having an exposed cable channel is acceptable and it would not be worth it to break open walls and ceilings to hide it.   But in your case you might say that pretty ceiling is there for a reason and covering it with a conduit is ugly.  You might also find it absurdly expensive. That's entirely your decision.

If you want to do it, you need a ring and cover to go over the existing (probably round) junction box, an inside corner to meet the ceiling, and a ring and backer to mount the light on.  Depending on the weight of the light you may need to locate it under a joist.  Make sure to buy all the right bits at every interface to protect the cable from the sharp edges of the channel.  You don't have to run 14/2 NM in it, you can run loose #14 wires.  Putting NM 14/2 cable inside the smallest metal raceway is challenging.

A better approach is low voltage LED lighting.  You can ask a new question about approaches to that, but assuming the existing light is switched, you can keep the switch, install an outlet (that will be switched) where the light is now, and run low voltage wiring from there to strip lights that light up all the shelves and floor space evenly.  I suspect that will cost less than the wiremold and give better results.

Comment: GREAT idea with the low voltage.